# How do I use optparse to just split the command-line arguments into options and positional args?

Tags: python, optparse

For example, if I give

```
test.py -a SOMETHING 1 2 3
```

after option parsing, I want two lists:

```
>> print opt
>> ['-a', 'SOMETHING']

>> print args
>> ['1', '2', '3']
```

Is it possible to do this using optparse?

Comment: It's probably possible, but I wanted to note that optparse is being deprecated in favor of argparse, which is tons better in my opinion. :)

Comment: @JohnDoe - I agree about argparse. But I am stuck for some time with Python2.6 and do need to use optparse for now.

Comment: Akash: you can put a local copy of [argparse.py](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/argparse) in your PYTHONPATH and use it in Python2.6. It maybe be less work for you in the end since you won't have to port your optparse program to argparse later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [optparse documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html) it seems like you can do this:

```
import optparse

parser = optparse.OptionParser()
parser.add_option("-a", action="store", type="string", dest="a")

(opt, arg) = parser.parse_args()
print "Opt:", opt
print "Arg:", arg
```

If I run this using your command line `python test.py -a SOMETHING 1, 2, 3` it prints:

```
Opt: {'a': 'SOMETHING'}
Arg: ['1', '2', '3']
```

which seems very close to the desired result.

If you really must have the options as a list, you could add something like this to the code above:

```
o = list()
for k in vars(opt):
    o.append(k)
    o.append(getattr(opt, k))
print "List Opt:", o
```

For me this prints:

```
List Opt: ['a', 'SOMETHING']
```